# curl not getting response

Tags: curl, request, hosting, shared-hosting

I am not getting response to the following in hosting server opalstack. While other hosting service have no problem.

```
curl -v -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36" https://www.nseindia.com
```

Getting following output:

```
* About to connect() to www.nseindia.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.37.45.217...
* Connected to www.nseindia.com (23.37.45.217) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=www.nseindia.com,O=National Stock Exchange of India Ltd.,L=Mumbai,ST=Maharashtra,C=IN
*       start date: Oct 22 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*       expire date: Nov 10 23:59:59 2021 GMT
*       common name: www.nseindia.com
*       issuer: CN=GeoTrust RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.nseindia.com
> Accept: */*
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36
```

and then it hangs without any response

Getting proper response for other websites in opalstack.

What could be the problem in opalstack. What should I tell them to look for. They have not been able to identify the issue till now.

Any hint etc will be welcome.

If this is not the forum for this question, please guide where I should be posting it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That may happen if 443 is not opened on the server or you have some firewall rules that restrict your access. So `curl` just can't connect to the server.

Comment: should not be a port problem as access to other websites is successful. 
There's no firewall rule too specifically blocking this site.

Comment: I want to say that's not a curl issue. It's a server problem.